# How do I use v-model with an object using Vue and Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, v-model, vuedx

I'm using Vue 3 with Typescript, and I've got a simple component that looks like this:

### My Radio Switch Component

```
<template>
 <div v-for="unit in unitOptions" :key="unit.label" >
    <input 
      type="radio"
      v-model="units"
      :value="unit"
      :id="unit.type"
    >
    <label :for="unit.type">{{ unit.type }}</label
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import { Unit } from "../common/types";

export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      unitOptions: [
        {
          type: 'Imperial',
          label: 'fl oz',
          nPerGlass: 8,
        },
        {
          type: 'Metric',
          label: 'mL',
          nPerGlass: 240,
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    units: {
      get(): Unit {
        return this.$store.state.options.units
      },
      set(value:Unit): void {
        this.$store.commit('updateUnits', value)
      },
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

It's a radio switch bound to the computed property, `units`. Everything work fine in development mode, but `vuedx-typescheck` throws errors because I'm the value bound to v-model isn't a string.

### Error Output

```
src/pages/Settings.vue:25:23 - error VueDX/TS2322: Type 'Unit' is not assignable to type 'string | number | string[] | undefined'.
  Type 'Unit' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.
22 |           <input 
23 |             type="radio"
24 |             v-model="units"
   |                      ~~~~~
25 |             :value="unit"
26 |             :id="unit.type"
    node_modules/@vue/runtime-dom/dist/runtime-dom.d.ts:588:4
 589 | }
 590 | 
 591 | export interface KeygenHTMLAttributes extends HTMLAttributes {
     |                             ~~~~~
 592 |   autofocus?: boolean
 593 |   challenge?: string
    The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'ElementAttrs<InputHTMLAttributes>'

src/pages/Settings.vue:25:23 - error VueDX/TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Unit'.
22 |           <input 
23 |             type="radio"
24 |             v-model="units"
   |                      ~~~~~
25 |             :value="unit"
26 |             :id="unit.type"

src/pages/Settings.vue:26:15 - error VueDX/TS2322: Type '{ type: string; label: string; nPerGlass: number; }' is not assignable to type 'string | number | string[] | undefined'.
  Type '{ type: string; label: string; nPerGlass: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.
23 |             type="radio"
24 |             v-model="units"
25 |             :value="unit"
   |              ~~~~~
26 |             :id="unit.type"
27 |           >
    node_modules/@vue/runtime-dom/dist/runtime-dom.d.ts:588:4
 589 | }
 590 | 
 591 | export interface KeygenHTMLAttributes extends HTMLAttributes {
     |                             ~~~~~
 592 |   autofocus?: boolean
 593 |   challenge?: string
    The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'ElementAttrs<InputHTMLAttributes>'

src/pages/Settings.vue:26:15 - error VueDX/TS17001: JSX elements cannot have multiple attributes with the same name.
23 |             type="radio"
24 |             v-model="units"
25 |             :value="unit"
   |              ~~~~~
26 |             :id="unit.type"
27 |           >
```

The core of the issue seems to be that the HTML Input only expects string values, while I'm using an object here. That makes sense in Vanilla HTML, but this is Vue, and objects can absolutely be used as input values. Also in the mix, the tool thinks I'm setting the `value` attribute twice...which I'm not.

So what's the solution here? Am I missing some important config file that would make this work? Am I supposed to just use strings with inputs in Typescript, ignoring this feature of Vue?

Comment: maybe you can user `get(): any {` to try to see if it works

Comment: This isn't typescript, it's your opinionated library `vue-developer-experience`, as you can see this is being thrown from VueDX.

Comment: There are a few things that need clarifacation, you have set the return value of get() to Unit but are returning units is that correct? Adding the Unit type to your question might help. Is using v-model and :value toegther also causing problems? As I thought using v-model would ignore value attribute but you are also v-binding the value with :value - I wonder if that's throwing it for a loop to do with the multiple attributes error.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I think you're right, I found a related bug in the vuedx repo: https://github.com/znck/vue-developer-experience/issues/198 VueDX is included with their default setup, so I assumed the fault was in my code. I'll post a workaround when I've got one.

Comment: v-model and :value _are_ the same property, only indirectly. v-model is used when you want 2-way data binding, :value when you only need 1-way, but not both at the same time on the same element.

At the very least, you're getting _unit_ as a member of an array in a data prop called _unitOptions_ but your v-model is an array returned from a computed prop. These are two different elements from two different arrays, I'd be confused too. Try dropping :value and make sure your store has those props you need.

Alternatively drop v-model add an @change handler that does the work.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like there are a few bugs in the development tool `@vuedx/typescript-plugin-vue`.

The one effecting me here was https://github.com/znck/vue-developer-experience/issues/198

I removed the typecheck step from my build process and moved on. The project is still in "alpha" status, although it is included by default when scaffolding a new project.

Comment: For anyone looking at this today, Vue 3 is now the new default, and a lot of the sub-projects have been taken out of beta and alpha status. I haven't looked back into this issue, but it may have been fixed.